# Importing data from trial account to different subscription

Tags: import, azure-video-indexer

I have an older videoindexer.ai trial account that i would like to download my videos from.  however, when I try to run an import from the trial site to my new Azure internal FTE non-production subscription, the process fails.   Thanks